# BuildConfingField string not set correctly

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a BuildConfingField in my gradle script here my code

```
def VERSION_NAME = "3.1.0b"
def VERSION=VERSION_NAME+"-"+getDate();

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        setProperty("archivesBaseName",POM_ARTIFACT_ID +"-"+VERSION_NAME+"-"+  getDate())
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false // non usare MAI proguard a meno di non aver ispezionato bene il codice!!
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION", VERSION
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField "String", "VERSION",VERSION
        }
    }

}

def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyMMddHHmm')  //'yyyyMMddHHmmss'
    return formattedDate
}
```

What I get is:

```
 public static final String VERSION = 3.1.0b-1605021144;
```

This brings compilation error.
Anyone can help on getting the string defined correctly?

Comment: try `'\"${VERSION}\"'` instead of `VERSION` with `buildConfigField`

Comment: Nope. I get 
    public static final String VERSION = "${VERSION}";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"\"${VERSION}\""` or `'"'+VERSION+'"'`.